Azure pipeline with GitGuardian
I'm trying to integrate Gitguardian into Azure DevOps pipeline.
According to Gitguardian documentation this is the pipeline that should be executed:
jobs: 
- job: GitGuardianShield
  container:
    image: gitguardian/ggshield:latest
    options: -u 0
  displayName: 'GitGuardian Container'
  steps:
  - script: |
      ggshield secret scan ci
    env:
      GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY: $(GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY)
    displayName: 'Scan for secrets with GitGuardian'


Yet all I get are errors
Starting: Initialize containers
DockerActionRetries variable value: True
/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
'
##[warning]Docker version failed, back off 00:00:10 seconds before retry.
/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
'
##[warning]Docker version failed, back off 00:00:10 seconds before retry.
/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
'
##[warning]Docker version failed, back off 00:00:10 seconds before retry.
/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
'
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/usr/bin/docker', arguments 'version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}''.
Finishing: Initialize containers



Edit:
I have added also this but same errors are prompted.
- job: DockerPermissions
  steps:
  - script: |
      sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
    displayName: 'Add current user to Docker group'

- job: GitGuardianShield
  dependsOn: DockerPermissions
**rest of pipeline**

Also, I want to avoid the fact that it always asks me to input my password when DockerPermissions is being executed.

What kind of agent are you using? Can you try to use Microsoft-hosted agent to run the Pipeline? Based on my test, the same yaml sample can work in Microsoft-hosted agent.

@KevinLu-MSFT i'm using self host agent on my ubuntu machine

Have you tried to log in to the ubuntu machine and run the command: sudo usermod -aG docker useraccountname to grant the permission to the user which is used to run agent.

Don't run these commands in 2 separate jobs. Each job will potentially run on a different agent and changes made in one job may not carry over into the 2nd.

@jessehouwing yes i thought about it but i didn't succeed into creating a valid pipeline. Can you share your valid pipeline please?

@KevinLu-MSFT yes i did that but same errors are prompted

@roteki After you running the command to set the permission, have you restarted your agent service?

@roteki What action are you doing when seeing this error? Can you share more details?

@roteki Can you confirm if you are still having the issue in pipeline?

@roteki Can you help us confirm  if it can work after running the command sudo usermod -aG docker useraccountname and restart the agent service?

Or you can add answer to share the steps to solve the issue. This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.
